# apt-get tries to get InRelease which does not exists anymore

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

My distrib is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Since some time, apt-get update it stuck. After hours of investigation, it seems that the file http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
does not exists anymore. But the Release file exists.

I've also tried with other repositories.

I can't find where the system decides to get InRelease and not Release.

What can I do to fix that?

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit:

apt version: `apt 1.0.1ubuntu2`

ouput of `apt-cache policy apt`:

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.0.1ubuntu2.17
  Candidate: 1.0.1ubuntu2.17
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1ubuntu2.17 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

---

Edit:

```
$ ls /var/lib/apt/lists/ | grep -i release
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release
archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release.gpg
archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_InRelease
archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release
archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release.gpg
archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_InRelease
security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_InRelease


$ grep -v ^# /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe main multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main multiverse universe
```

Comment: What version of apt are you running? please add the output of `apt-cache policy apt`. As far as I can make out, the `InRelease` file was introduced *after* 14.04 as part of the [AptByHash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptByHash) mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot @steeldriver . I've edited the question with the information you requested.

Comment: @MichaelHooreman Add this command output to your question: `ls /var/lib/apt/lists/ | grep -i release` also your `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Ravexina Thanks a lot. I've edited the question according to your suggestions.

Comment: @MichaelHooreman I search a little bit and I found some repositories for trusty with `InRelease` file, I asked for that output to see if any of  your lists has been downloaded in `InRelease` version.  I'm not sure if it's going to work for you, anyway, give it a shot... `sudo cp -r /var/lib/apt/lists{,.bk}` : to get a backup of your apt lists direcetory, then `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. finally `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Thanks @Ravexina
Unfortunately, I've already tried to renew `/var/lib/apt/lists` and it doesn't helps.

Comment: @Ravexina it worked that time; I don't understand, because it didn't worked previously. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Are you still looking for answer?

Comment: No, I'm not. Solved by piece of luck I'd say. Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, lots of things have been tried, many times. Last attempt to fix it by renewing `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` worked. I don't know why, because it didn't worked previously...

Nothing more to explain, sorry.